# Is there a way to prevent the editing of HTML and CSS contents in a page using Firebug-like tools?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Is there a way to prevent the editing of HTML and CSS contents in a page using Firebug-like tools?

I found that some users are editing some values in hidden fields and some contents which written between a div or span tag for gaining some profits. They are doing mostly by editing with help of tools like firebug. Is there any way to identify such modifications? The problem here is that the values they are editing is generated when the page is compiled. The page is developed in PHP. The editing is done mostly in between the tags.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: Bit harsh? In any case, isn't it better to help them and point them in the right direction? It's a well written simple question to which there is already a good clear simple answer.

Comment: +1 for a simple, clear, question that is relevant to many people. We were all noobs once.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Nope, sorry. Even if you could, users could just submit the form to your site using some other tool.

The golden rule here is: **Never trust user input**. Be sure to validate everything on the server side (in php) and look up any important values from your database instead of trusting whatever came from the user.